# sql golang invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference when do query

Tags: sql, go, runtime-error, runtime

i am trying to insert data after the connection, when i command the logic of `INSERT...` i was able to connect to the database, but when i uncommand them , i got error

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x0 pc=0x40f8e2a]
```

here is my function :

```
func Connect() (*sql.DB, error) {
    db, err := sql.Open("postgres", os.Getenv("PG_URL"))
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    defer db.Close()

    stmt, _ := db.Prepare("INSERT INTO users(name, email, password) VALUES(?,?,?)")
    res, err := stmt.Exec("test", "test@mail.com", "12344")

    if err != nil{
        panic(err.Error())
    }
    fmt.Println(res)
    fmt.Println("Successfully connected!")
    return db, nil
}
```

I have tried to do the same thing also like this [article go sql](http://go-database-sql.org/modifying.html)
and have the same issue
do I wrong implement this?

Comment: It's difficult to tell without the full stacktrace. Also: check the error returned by `db.Prepare`

Comment: `Connect` should not close the db handle if it is returning it to the caller. What's the caller gonna do with a closed connection?

Comment: Note that in general it is not necessary to call `Open` more than once, the `*sql.DB` is a *pool* of connections and it's safe for concurrent use, therefore, *in general*, you don't need to close `*sql.DB`, ever, and if you desperately want to, do that in `main`. See: https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#Open

Comment: i think i found out , that is because `?` and i changed to `$1` it was worked

Comment: @srxlnx if that's the case then you could have saved yourself some time by not ignoring the error returned by `Prepare`. In the future, please do recognize that in Go the error values are returned for a reason and are intended to be handled explicitly, not ignored.

Comment: i am using Postgres and i got the error that i can't get the `.LastInsertId()`, how can i get the id of new insert data ? do u know? @mkopriva

Comment: The `LastInsertId` availability is dependent on the driver you're using. So saying "postgres" is not enough. Either way, in general, you can use the `RETURNING` clause to return the modified row data, note that if you do use the `RETURNING` clause, you have to use `QueryRow` (for single row insert), or `Query` (for multi row insert) instead of the `Exec` method.

Comment: As an example, the `lib/pq` driver specifically mentions that it doesn't provide support for `LastInsertId` and includes examples on how to use the `RETURNING` clause. See here: https://godoc.org/github.com/lib/pq#hdr-Queries

Comment: i was looking at this first :) https://medium.com/@leeprovoost/get-lastinsertedid-when-using-postgres-and-golang-database-sql-package-ca55ea23c2d5, but thx for helping

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I bet a dollar/euro/frank that the NPE is on the line executing the prepared statement and that if you check the only error you ignored it won't be `nil` and it will tell you what's wrong.

Comment: What is NPE stands for ?

Comment: @Mahdimehrabi NPE is Null Pointer Exception, the same as Nil Pointer Dereference.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with sqlite.

As Ivaylo Novakov described in his answer I had to log the err of the prepare statement (which i ignored like you before `stmt, _`)

For me it was running okay as long as i was developing but when I created my final binary i forgot to enable `cgo`).

The err got the hint:

```
Binary was compiled with 'CGO_ENABLED=0', go-sqlite3 requires cgo to work. This is a stub
```

Comment: Never skip checking errors. It's just not worth it. :)

Comment: yep, you're probably right. My statement was static without variables. So i thought i would be fine but of course not :D